# React Native Fetch Request Network Error

Tags: react-native, fetch

I've seen previous answers on similar queries to this, but i'm still seeing a network error.

Here is my code:

```
let base64 = require('base-64');

let url = 'https://super_secret.com';
let username = '**supersecret**';
let password = '**supersecret**';

let headers = new Headers();
//headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/json');
headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password));

let APIcall = function checkOrgCode() {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

If i comment out headers.headers and test a simple un-authorized API like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 then everything works fine, so clearly authoriation is failing.

When i test my API and headers in postman everything is fine though. I've also tried directly putting the base64 encoded string directly in the headers rather than using the encode function in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erm, so the issue was that the URL i am using isn't in place. I'd been using a hostname file hack which ofcourse works from postman on my PC, but not other mobile devices where i am testing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `new Headers()` to create the headers, try just a basic object to make life easy:

```
return fetch(url, {
  method: '**PROPER METHOD HERE**',
  headers: {
    // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Basic ${base64.encode(username + ":" + password)}`
  }
})
```